# Printing a local PDF From a UIWebView Scaling Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, uiwebview, airprint

I have a rather simple function that prints a webview. However, when I am printing a local pdf, all of the pages are scaled down to about half size instead of filling the page. I have tried modifying the viewPrintFormatter margins and a few other things but nothing seems to change. I have tried toggling "showsPageRange" after setting the print formatter but that doesn't seem to change anything either. Has anyone run into this issue/know how to make the pages print at full size?

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
Class printInfoClass = NSClassFromString( @"UIPrintInfo" );

id pic = [printControllerClass sharedPrintController];
id printInfo = [printInfoClass printInfo];

// setup print info
[printInfo setOutputType:0];
[pic setPrintInfo:printInfo];
[pic setPrintFormatter:[_webView viewPrintFormatter]];
[pic presentAnimated:NO completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. What finally solved it:

Instead of using this property:

`printController.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()`

use this one for PDFs:

`printController.printingItem = data // the PDF data`

Be aware that the latter doesn't work for plain texts, so in that case you'll prefer to use the former.